# if-else if-else no funciona, no sé por qué

Tags: java, poo

Estoy validando el peso del electrodoméstico:

```
if (this.peso >= 0 && this.peso < 19) {

        this.valor_extra += 10;

    }else if (this.peso >= 20 && this.peso < 49) {

        this.valor_extra += 50;

    }else if (this.peso >= 50 && this.peso <= 79) {

        this.valor_extra += 80;

    }else if (this.peso >= 80) {

        this.valor_extra += 100;
    }
```

Lo he visto mil veces y esta bien validado, pero por alguna razon el no valida las demás opciones, simplemente le agrega 10 aunque el peso sea mayor o igual a 20

```
    System.out.println("Ingrese color");
    setColor(datos.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Ingrese consumo electrico");
    setConsumo(datos.next().charAt(0));
    System.out.println("Ingrese precio");
    setPrecio(datos.nextDouble());
    System.out.println("Ingrese peso");
    setPeso(datos.nextdouble());
```

aqui pido los datos

```
    public Electrodomestico (String color, char consumo, double precio, double peso) {

    this.color = validarColor(color)?color:color_defecto;
    this.consumo_electrico = validarConsumo(consumo)?consumo:consumo_electrico_defecto;
    this.precio_base = precio + aumentarPrecio();
    this.peso = peso;

}
```

constructor del objeto

```
    public double aumentarPrecio() {

    if (this.peso >= 0 && this.peso <= 19) {

        this.valor_extra += 10;

    }else if (this.peso >= 20 && this.peso <= 49){

        this.valor_extra += 50;

    }else if (this.peso >= 50 && this.peso <=79) {

        this.valor_extra += 80;

    }else if (this.peso >= 80) {

        this.valor_extra += 100;
    }       
    }
```

Función donde valida el peso para agregarle valor extra.

Comment: Tu título es de poca ayuda y tu código no es un [mcve], considera mejorar tu pregunta para obtener respuestas más rápido

Comment: ?, que mas verificable que la validacion? es una simple validacion xD, no hay que ser gran genio para saber que estoy intentando hacer ahi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema no está en la validación, el problema es el orden de asignación de valores a las variables:

```
this.precio_base = precio + aumentarPrecio();
this.peso = peso;
```

debe ser primero la asignación de la variable peso:

```
this.peso = peso;
this.precio_base = precio + aumentarPrecio();
```

No olvides corregir los rangos superiores.

Comment: if (this.getPeso() >= 0 && this.getPeso() <= 19) {
            
            this.valor_extra += 10;
            
        }else {
            
            this.valor_extra += 100;
        } 

probe validando asi simple e igual me agrega 10 y no 100, el peso debe estar entre 0 o menor-igual 19, si no agrega 100, me sigue agregando 10

Comment: El rango que utilizas funciona para enteros, pero si es double 19.5 queda fuera de rango. ¿Como asignas el valor a la variable Peso?

Comment: la variable peso es de tipo double

Comment: inserte peso como 30 y como es double automaticamente seria 30.0 pero aun asi lo puede validar

Comment: ¿Lo haces una línea antes de la validación? ¿Puedes publicar más código de asignación de valor a la variable?

Comment: lo publique en respuesta para que veas como hago

Comment: <3 que estupido soy

Comment: A todos nos pasa, jajaja. Saludos